# Getting extra single quotes in output

Tags: python

I'm solving a simple code in Python to print randomly generated ticket number. But when I'm printing list of ticket number it is giving extra single quotes.

Please refer to below code:

```
#PF-Exer-22
import random

def generate_ticket(airline,source,destination,no_of_passengers):
    ticket_number_list=[]
    src = source[0:3]
    dest = destination[0:3]
    listof_passonger = []
    random_number_list = []
    random_number = 0
    random_number = 102
    for loop  in range(0, no_of_passengers):

        #if(random_number in random_number_list):
        #random_number = random.randint(101,500)
        #else:
        #random_number_list.append(random_number_list)
        random_number = random_number + 1
        ticket_number = airline + ":" + src + ":" + dest + ":" + str(random_number)
        ticket_number_list.append(ticket_number)

    return ticket_number_list


print(generate_ticket("AI","Bangalore","London",7))
```

while executing above code my **output** is :-

```
['AI:Ban:Lon:103', 'AI:Ban:Lon:104', 'AI:Ban:Lon:105', 'AI:Ban:Lon:106', 'AI:Ban:Lon:107', 'AI:Ban:Lon:108', 'AI:Ban:Lon:109']
```

but my **expected output** is :-

```
[AI:Ban:Lon:103,AI:Ban:Lon:104,AI:Ban:Lon:105,AI:Ban:Lon:106,AI:Ban:Lon:107]
```

As you can see there is no single code is expected output.

Please refer to the below image:

[image: This is the image where my test cases are failing.]

Comment: It's the excepted result. You are printing a list, and in that list, there are strings. So Python add `'`.

Comment: When you print a list, all `str` items in it will be wrapped in single quotes by default. If you want it to be as you expect, you will have to loop over items and construct a string. Or use `join`

Comment: Your output is list of `strings` and this is how it will print in Python. If you explain why you don't need those single quotes around string we can help you better?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Hi Akshay, Actually this is the question from infytq.com website from where I'm practicing python. and the expected output is their own output. when I'm verifying their test cases its failing therefore I need Some other solution to remove those quotes or else Need some other solution to get expected output

Comment: @reportgunner  hii all, please refer to the Solution again I have edited and added Image where my test cases are failing. please refer to that and then provide me solution.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. The image you posted makes me think this is an excercise in some kind of education - perhaps there are materials in the education that explain how to do this ? Have you checked ? What did you find ?

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior when dealing with a `list of strings` in python.

Example

```py
# Declaring a list 
L = [1, "a" , "string" , 1+2] 
print L 
L.append(6) 
print L 
L.pop() 
print L 
print L[1]
```

Output

```py
[1, 'a', 'string', 3]
[1, 'a', 'string', 3, 6]
[1, 'a', 'string', 3]
a
```

In case you don't want to display the `'` in your output. You can print the elements individually or make use of the `join()` function as show below.

```py
# Sample code
val = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print(':'.join(val))

# Result
A:B:C
```

Comment: I think the separators should still be `,`, not `:` (those are just part of the strings), but I'm sure OP can figure out how to change that.

Comment: Yup! It's just a sample to help understand how `join()` works. Using `,` will get confusing as they are also present while just printing out the list object.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a list of strings. When you try to print this list it shows that the individual elements in the list are strings. 
So, to get the desired output all you need to do is the following:

1. Store the result of your function in a list.
2. Access individual items on this list which will then be in your desired format.

The resulting code will look like this

```
def generate_ticket(airline,source,destination,no_of_passengers):
    ticket_number_list=[]
    src = source[0:3]
    dest = destination[0:3]
    listof_passonger = []
    random_number_list = []
    random_number = 0
    random_number = 102
    for loop  in range(0, no_of_passengers):

        #if(random_number in random_number_list):
            #random_number = random.randint(101,500)
        #else:
            #random_number_list.append(random_number_list)
        random_number = random_number + 1
        ticket_number = airline + ":" + src + ":" + dest + ":" + str(random_number)
        ticket_number_list.append(ticket_number)

    return ticket_number_list

print(generate_ticket("AI","Bangalore","London",7))
l = generate_ticket("AI","Bangalore","London",7)
for item in l:
    print(item)
```